# Gnucash: how to add multiple rates in the price scatterplot

Tags: gnucash

If it is possible, how can I add multiple investment rates/currencies/etc within a single price scatterplot? I know how to add one rate. I just want to have this report for myself.

Or, as a first time user, if you have suggestions for how to improve the specification of the question, please let me know. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, after some more searching: 
Use menu:

```
Reports | Sample & Custom | Samle Multicoumn Report
```

And then add the various accounts from the left side to the right side of the UI view.